# How to speedup jQuery replace image on hover

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I wrote a code to change the images on a hover.

The problem is that when the mouse moves fast from one "item" to another, it messes up images.

How to fix that?

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/icon1.png" data-original="img/icon1.png" data-hover="img/icon1-hover.png">
            <span>Title</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="img/icon2.png" data-original="img/icon2.png" data-hover="img/icon2-hover.png">
            <span>Title</span>
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.items .item a').hover(function(){
newsrc = $(this).children('img').data("hover");
$(this).children('img').fadeOut(100, function() {
    $(this).attr('src', newsrc).fadeIn();
}); 
}, function(){
    oldsrc = $(this).children('img').data("original");
    $(this).children('img').fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).attr('src', oldsrc).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "it messes up images" means?

Comment: I mean that icon1 replaces icon2 for example.

Comment: Try putting `var` in front of `newsrc` and `oldsrc` and see if your issue persists.

Comment: Wow, it actually fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newsrc = $(this).children('img').data("hover");
oldsrc = $(this).children('img').data("original");
```

These two lines do not have a `var` on the front of them, which will cause them to not be scoped to the function they are in, so swapping quickly from image to image can have some bleed over since you are sharing variables.

Put `var` on the front of them, to make the variables unique per function invocation.

```
var newsrc = $(this).children('img').data("hover");
var oldsrc = $(this).children('img').data("original");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've asked how to do this using jQuery, but please allow me to offer another solution.
Usually, when there is no need to use javascript (especially jQuery nowadays) I try to avoid it if I can get the same result using **CSS only**.

I believe if I understand you correctly that you are trying to show with fade in and out an image on hover to replace the other image.

The code below does that without javascript.
There is a pitfall that you will load images that perhaps will never show, therefore you might would like to lazy load the images that supposed to fade in using javascript.

Good luck and may the force be with you.

```css
 .items {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }  
 .items .item {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
 .items .item span{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 20px;
        text-align: center;

    }
 .items .item img:nth-child(2){
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }
 .items .item:hover img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="items">
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.facetheforce.today/han-old/400" alt="Han Solo Old">
                <img src="http://www.facetheforce.today/han/400" alt="Han Solo">
                <span>Han Solo</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://www.facetheforce.today/luke-old/400" alt="Luke Old">
                <img src="http://www.facetheforce.today/luke/400" alt="Luke">
                <span>Luke</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```